# Unknown attribute 'user_id' for Comment works locally but not on Heroku - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Locally i can create comment just fine but on heroku i get this error

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'user_id' for Comment.):
app[web.1]:   app/controllers/blog/comments_controller.rb:9:in `create' 



  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"g83t8MpETbolCJq0vYku4SbnaZAro5ggXUI1PGVFJ18xneGcGCWQPjXHTfgBKBIP2/5WqHjfxf2d12+Pyq4PNA==", "comment"=>{"name"=>"test", "email"=>"tester@kostis.com", "body"=>"teste", "user_id"=>"1", "post_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create comment"}
```

here is my controller

```
class Blog::CommentsController < Blog::BaseController

  def new

    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    if @comment.save
      flash[:success] = "Comment successfully created!"
      redirect_to blog_post_url(@comment.post)
    else
      flash[:warning] = "There was an error with your comment. Please scroll down to see the errors."
      @post = @comment.post
      render 'blog/posts/show'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @comment = Comment.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @comment = Comment.find_by(id: params[:id])
    if @comment.update(comment_params)
      flash[:success] = "Successfully updated..."
      redirect_to blog_post_path(@comment.post)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private
      def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:body,:name,:email,:user_id,:post_id)
      end
end
```

UPDATE:

my local migration file is this

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.text :body
      t.boolean :spam, default: false
      t.references :post, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

but by running rails c on heroku and checking the actualy "Comment" structure there is no user_id, how is that possible?

Comment: did you forget to migrate database on deploy?

Comment: migrations are ok. everything is migrated.

Answer (score 1):

#### If the user owns the comment: (comment `belongs_to: :user`)

Load the user:

```
user = User.find([id])
```

Then create the comment:

```
user.comments.new(comment_params)
```

#### If the post owns the comment: (comment `belongs_to: :post`)

Load the user:

```
post = Post.find([id])
```

Then create the comment:

```
post.comments.new(comment_params)
```

Try not to allow the client to say who they are - someone could easily fake that they are a different user then who they say. [JWT](//jwt.io) is a good solution for this.

Comment: JWT seems unnecessary. Just use `current_user`

Comment: If you have an api it's super useful

Comment: whats the issue with how its done really? i mean in terms of plain working? clearly from the params it gets a user id.

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou Anyone can fake their account - and act as someone else, even an admin.

Comment: @penne12 thank you for your input but that is something else, please check my post again i discovered something new thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot about this (if it works locally, as you say)?

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Comment: actually no this is not it. migrations are ok.

Comment: **heroku restart** was done well? Sorry for persistence. :)